# Is there a difference on the PSVR between the PS4 Pro and the regular PS4?

Tags: ps4, playstation-vr

*Please note that I don't own a PS4 nor a PSVR Headset*

Is there a difference when you use the PSVR on a PS4 Pro versus a regular PS4 Fat/Slim? (Framerate, Resolution, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in tracking, no difference in responsiveness, and no difference in frame rate (with the exception of a few games like the Miku Hatsune games which run at 90fps natively on the PS4 Pro rather than at 120fps reprojected from 60fps on the standard PS4).